# permission issue for collectstatic in docker-compose

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to run django application and serve it using ngnix.When i run docker

```
exec DOCKERNAME /bin/sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

following error occured

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/src/static/admin/js/popup_response.js'
```

How to run collectstatic command with sudo permission in docker-compose

Comment: If you want to write to that directory after the image is built, why not chown it to the user the container runs as (when building the image), then you will not need sudo.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
docker-compose run --user root {DOCKERNAME} sh -c "chown -R {USERNAME}:root /src/static"
```

where `{USERNAME}` is user name from Dockerfile.

E.g. I have `USER django` line in Dockerfile for `django` docker-compose service, therefore I should run:

```
docker-compose run --user root django sh -c "chown -R django:root /src/static"
```